# Why does Webpack put brackets around parameters passed in using --define?

Tags: webpack

I want to pass parameters into my website at compile time depending on whether it's for dev, test, or live.

So I build my app like this (using the integrated DefinePlugin)

```
webpack --define WEBPACK_CONFIG.webserviceUrl="NARF"
```

and use the parameter like this

```
declare const WEBPACK_CONFIG: any;    
const config =
{
    webserviceUrl : WEBPACK_CONFIG.webserviceUrl
};
export = config;
```

But the compiled output has brackets around my value

```
/***/ 243:
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {    
    "use strict";
    const config = {
        webserviceUrl: (NARF)
    };
    module.exports = config;
```

How do I stop Webpack adding brackets to parameters?

Comment: Just suggestion, not tested: `webpack --define WEBPACK_CONFIG.webserviceUrl="'NARF'"`

Comment: As a workaround after finding this bug (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2427) I found adding quotes works: webpack --define WEBPACK_CONFIG.webserviceUrl="'NARF'"

Comment: Thanks, Bob, just found that too. But I still want the weird braces gone...

Comment: I'm also having this issue (also using TS)